# Numbering a rows positional index relative to its siblings within a parent context

Tags: sequence

So, I have a table that contains numerous entries of text, but each one has a parent context that identifies the entries within a group, such as:

```
+------+-------+------+
| PKID | GrpID | Body |
+------+-------+------+
| 1    | 1     | a... |
+------+-------+------+
| 2    | 2     | b... |
+------+-------+------+
| 3    | 2     | c... |
+------+-------+------+
| 4    | 1     | d... |
+------+-------+------+
| 5    | 3     | e... |
+------+-------+------+
| 6    | 3     | f... |
+------+-------+------+
| 7    | 2     | g... |
+------+-------+------+
| 8    | 1     | h... |
+------+-------+------+
| 9    | 1     | i... |
+------+-------+------+
```

Now, I am trying to get a numeric value (calculated based on the rows position within the result, so it could be different each time based on what predicates are used) for the position of each row. So (I have ordered it by GrpID to make it easier to read, but imagine it was ordered naturally):

```
+------+-----+-------+------+
| PKID | Idx | GrpID | Body |
+------+-----+-------+------+
| 1    | 1   | 1     | a... |
+------+-----+-------+------+
| 4    | 2   | 1     | d... |
+------+-----+-------+------+
| 8    | 3   | 1     | h... |
+------+-----+-------+------+
| 9    | 4   | 1     | i... |
+------+-----+-------+------+
| 2    | 1   | 2     | b... |
+------+-----+-------+------+
| 3    | 2   | 2     | c... |
+------+-----+-------+------+
| 7    | 3   | 2     | g... |
+------+-----+-------+------+
| 5    | 1   | 3     | e... |
+------+-----+-------+------+
| 6    | 2   | 3     | f... |
+------+-----+-------+------+
```

What query could be performed on such a dataset that would give me such a result?

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: answered (partially), but i missed that sequence. which database engine you use ?

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: DBMS agnostic for the moment, I would prefer to stay as close to MySQL as possible, but am willing to use another

Comment: @Colin'tHart Nothing, I have no idea where to start on such a thing

Comment: MySQL doesn't support analytic functions which is what both answers so far have used. Which DBMS *are* you using?

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server and other systems that support ROW_NUMBER...

```
SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY GrpID
        ORDER BY PKID
    ) AS Idx
FROM YourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

FOR MS SQL 2012 server

```
select id, grp , grpn = ROW_NUMBER()
                                      OVER (  PARTITION BY [grp]
                                                    ORDER BY [grp]
                                                   )  from list order by grp,id
```

SEE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8d6b9/1